# Will a (landline) phone bought in France work in Germany?

Tags: germany, france, telephone

I have a landline phone bought in France. It comes with two connectors.  I believe the first follows some common standard and the second is exclusively French.

Will this phone work in Germany?  Are any of these connectors in use in Germany?

French plug:

[image]

Possibly a standard plug (9 mm wide, what standard is it?):

[image]

Comment: The second photo looks like a standard RJ-11 jack. That is a standard connector used pretty much world wide as far as I know. Certainly, it is the standard land line connector in the United States. See [Wikipedia topic Registered Jack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Registered_jack). As for the first one, that may be a French only connector.

Comment: @RichardChambers Technically that's an RJ-11 *plug* :) ... the jack would be the part in the wall into which this plugs.

Comment: @RichardChambers: Phone connectors can actually vary quite a lot between countries. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_plug for a big list.

Comment: Then the question is: is it likely that the phone will work in Germany, possibly with [a TAE / RJ11 adapter](https://www.amazon.de/Wentronic-Adapter-Stecker-Kupplung-schwarz/dp/B000VN1DM0/) (from what I could gather)?  I am trying to decide whether to bring it or sell it and get a new one.  It's not valuable, but selling everything is a pain.

Comment: I'm almost sure the phone will work, only you'll need converter because of funny plugs in Germany. The phone bought in Germany worked in Poland without issues with normal (jack?) plug (the photo below). 
On the phone side the plug was normal, only the 2nd part is 'mutated'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

German phone lines usually end with a TAE connector (Telekommunikation-Anschluss-Einheit):

https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telekommunikations-Anschluss-Einheit

The main question would be - will you have internet connection via that landline.

If it is a pure landline, it will use the TAE connector, and there are adapters for RJ-45 jack to TAE connector. I do not know however if the dial tones are different.

Anyways, pure landline phone - while still available - are getting exceedingly rare and most telecommunication companies will try to shift people from direct landline connections to VoIP connections however.

Almost all companies (regardless of (V)DSL, cable or fibre connection) should provide you with a multi purpose router with built-in analogue to VoIP support accepting either TAE or RJ-11 (sometimes even RJ-45) connectors for analogue or ISDN phones.

Also the most popular routers in Germany can accept either ISDN or/and (depending on the model) analogue phones with RJ-11 connectors and connect to the TAE socket themselves and act as a mini PBX.